# how to load multiple xml files with saxon

Tags: xpath, saxon

I want to use saxon for xpath queries but i don't know to load multiple xml files.

I'm trying to use saxon with command line from windows

I read in saxon manual that i can use the command:

> Query.exe -s:myDataFile.xml -q:myQueryFile -o:myOutputFile

but i don't know how to load multiple xml files and not just one

edit:
I have many xml files myDataFile1.xml, myDataFile2.xml, myDataFile3.xml ... and i want to run the query to alla these files So i want to load all all files and then query them (I don't want to query every single file and then concatenate the results)

Comment: Do you want to run a query through multiple sources?

Comment: I have many xml files
g1.xml
g2.xml
g3.xml
...
and i want to run the query to alla these files
So i want to load all all files and then query them

(I don't want to query every single file and then concatenate the results)

Answer (score 7):

**Use the standard XPath 2.0 function [collection()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-collection).**

The documentation for the Saxon-specific implementation of `collection()` is **[here](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/functions/intro/fn_collection.html)**.

You can use the standard XPath 2.x **[collection()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-collection)** function, **[as implemented in Saxon 9.x](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.html)**

The Saxon implementation allows a search pattern to be used in the string-Uri argument of the function, thus you may be able to specify after the path of the directory a pattern for any filename starting with `report_` then having two other characters, then ending with `.xml`.

**Example**:

This XPath expression:

```
collection('file:///c:/?select=report_*.xml')
```

selects the document nodes of every XML document that resides in `c:\` in a file with name starting with `report_` then having a 0 or more characters, then ending with `.xml`.