# XSLT xml to xml grouping nodes and transform to other structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I'm having a xml document which I would like to transform from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<import:configuration xmlns:import="http://schemas.company.com/wsdl/domain/v2/import">
    <import:input>
        <import:file headers="1" group="MAPPING">
            <import:name>file001.txt</import:name>
            <import:separator><![CDATA[;]]></import:separator>
            <import:table>TAB00008_TECSPEC</import:table>
            <import:field primary="true">
                <import:name>VEMAR</import:name>
                <import:target>VEMAR</import:target>
                <import:type dbs="oracle" type="text">VARCHAR(3)</import:type>
                <import:reference>
                    <import:table>TAB00006_TECSPEC</import:table>
                    <import:field>VEMAR</import:field>
                </import:reference>
                <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
            </import:field>
            <import:field primary="true">
                <import:name>VENR</import:name>
                <import:target>VENR</import:target>
                <import:type dbs="oracle" type="numeric">NUMBER(7)</import:type>
                <import:reference>
                    <import:table>TAB00006_TECSPEC</import:table>
                    <import:field>VENR</import:field>
                </import:reference>
                <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
            </import:field>
            <import:field primary="true">
                <import:name>KNR</import:name>
                <import:target>KNR</import:target>
                <import:type dbs="oracle" type="numeric">NUMBER(9)</import:type>
                <import:reference>
                    <import:table>TAB00003_TECSPEC</import:table>
                    <import:field>KNR</import:field>
                </import:reference>
                <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
            </import:field>
            <import:field>
                <import:name>DATNEU</import:name>
                <import:target>DATNEU</import:target>
                <import:type dbs="oracle" type="date" format="YYYY.MM.DD">DATE</import:type>
                <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
            </import:field>
            <import:field>
                <import:name>VTYPE</import:name>
                <import:target>VTYPE</import:target>
                <import:type dbs="oracle" type="numeric">NUMBER(1)</import:type>
                <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
            </import:field>
            <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
        </import:file>
    </import:input>
</import:configuration>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<import:configuration xmlns:import="http://schemas.company.com/wsdl/domain/v2/import">
    <import:input>
        <import:file headers="1" group="MAPPING">
            <import:name>file001.txt</import:name>
            <import:separator><![CDATA[;]]></import:separator>
            <import:table>TAB00008_TECSPEC</import:table>
            <import:field primary="true">
                <import:name>VEMAR</import:name>
                <import:target>VEMAR</import:target>
                <import:type dbs="oracle" type="text">VARCHAR(3)</import:type>
                <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
            </import:field>
            <import:field primary="true">
                <import:name>VENR</import:name>
                <import:target>VENR</import:target>
                <import:type dbs="oracle" type="numeric">NUMBER(7)</import:type>
                <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
            </import:field>
            <import:field primary="true">
                <import:name>KNR</import:name>
                <import:target>KNR</import:target>
                <import:type dbs="oracle" type="numeric">NUMBER(9)</import:type>
                <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
            </import:field>
            <import:field>
                <import:name>DATNEU</import:name>
                <import:target>DATNEU</import:target>
                <import:type dbs="oracle" type="date" format="YYYY.MM.DD">DATE</import:type>
                <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
            </import:field>
            <import:field>
                <import:name>VTYPE</import:name>
                <import:target>VTYPE</import:target>
                <import:type dbs="oracle" type="numeric">NUMBER(1)</import:type>
                <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
            </import:field>
            <import:reference>
                <import:table>TAB00006_TECSPEC</table>
                <import:link>
                    <source>VEMAR</source>
                    <target>VEMAR</target>
                </import:link>
                <import:link>
                    <source>VENR</source>
                    <target>VENR</target>
                </import:link>              
            </import:reference>
            <import:reference>
                <import:table>TAB00003_TECSPEC</table>
                <import:link>
                    <source>KNR</source>
                    <target>KNR</target>
                </import:link>          
            </import:reference>         
            <import:description><![CDATA[]]></import:description>
        </import:file>
    </import:input>
</import:configuration>
```

I want to group all references (`</import:reference>` under `<import:field>`) and grouped by table transform them to one element as described above.

I was reading this posting/question: [XML to CSV with XSLT - Grouping nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326734/xml-to-csv-with-xslt-grouping-nodes) but I can't get this working to get the desired output.

My knowledge in xslt is not so deep. Can anybody give a hint how I could do this?

Comment: You need to tell what XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. I'm using http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html to make the transformation and not using a concrete implementation.

Comment: Well, you *should* use an actual XSLT processor. Copying stuff to websites is no way to do real work.

Comment: But here's a hint: You will need to combine two techniques to achieve your desired result. The first is called the *identity template*, the second   *Muenchian grouping*. (With an XSLT 2.0 capable processor you can use `<xsl:for-each-group>` instead, but freeformatter.com version uses XSLT 1.0). There are numerous examples and explanations of Muenchian grouping all over the Internet, please try on your own first.

Comment: Hi, I wrote my own xsl on this online tool using the for-each-group approach and not getting the desired result. That's why I'm asking here. Thus, the hints are no helping right now. Anyway, thanks for the time spent writing the comments. I'll try my own.

Comment: If you have tried on your own then you must have code to show. The main reason you have received no answers so far is that StackOverflow is not a "implement these requirements for me" service. We are here to *help you*, and that requires that we see where you are stuck so we can explain what your mistake is. Posting a complete solution that you can copy and paste does not move you forward in any way.

Comment: Hi, I can understand your mistrust. I'm not an expert to xsl-stylesheets. Otherwise I would not lose my time writing questions and reading blogs to get a solution. I just would write it straightforward.

Comment: Mistrust is not the issue. I must decide how I want to invest my time. When I decide that "giving help to strangers for free" is a good use of my time, then I still want to get *something* in return. The pattern "I have *this* and I want *that* and I have no idea so please help me" occurs too often on this website, so the question "What have you tried?" is a common reaction to it. Next time, simply include your attempt in your question, explain it a bit and point out which detail you are stuck with. People are *way* more open to questions asked in this fashion.

Comment: Alright. Just a suggestion, when I think someone wants something for free (btw legitime because nobody knows why this person is asking, maybe deadline, etc?) and I don't want to help, I just don't answer. Try it, really, it saves my time.

Comment: Please don't pull the "if you don't want to help, move along" argument on me. At least not as long as you try to define what "help" means. I don't care for other peoples deadlines, they have *zero* impact on me. However, it's a *fact* that you get help for free on this website. People invest countless hours of their lifetimes to help others, I'm no exception. In fact, I'm doing it right now. I have spent way more than the 3 minutes I needed to solve your problem explaining to you how to ask a better question next time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know which is your problem. You gave me advices that I already tried. Anything I do I get a comment from you starting from how I should work "Copying stuff to websites is no way to do real work" to making some assumptions like "If you have tried on your own then you must have code to show". Sorry, try to meet people with respect and ask what their problem is before you start to slam people. As I wrote, I'll try it myself. Thank you.

Comment: I am meeting you with respect. (**A**: Point out *one* comment that was not written in a calm and to-the-point tone. **B:** Explain how the two of my statements you chose to bring up are not true and reasonable.) You are the one who has his expectations upside down. I'm trying to explain to you why you have received no answer to your question. Even for a niche topic like XSLT this is unusual on StackOverflow. Consequently there must be something wrong with the question. Don't you think it's useful that you come to know what that is?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is too complicated. Things I've noted:

- You can use `<xsl:copy>` and `<xsl:copy-of>` to make copies of input nodes. You don't need to re-create them manually.
- You are overusing XPath functions. There is no need to be *this* specific.
- If you find yourself solving a complete task in a single template, you are misusing XSLT. (That's true for every programming language - if you cram everything into one function then there's something wrong.)

Your task is of the "I need a copy of the input file, but with a small modification" variety.

The basis for these task always is the *identity transform*.

```
<xsl:transform
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

This makes a verbatim copy of the input. Now to your small modifications. XSLT works through template matching, so we need an `<xsl:template>` for everything we want to make a modification to.

1. You want the `<import:reference>` removed from `<import:field>` in the final output. That's easy, write a template for them that produces no output:

   ```
   <xsl:template match="import:reference" />
   ```
2. You want a new `<import:reference>` inside the `<import:file>`, one per `<import:table>`. That's not so difficult, either. Write a template that matches `import:file`, copies most of it and appends something for each `import:table` group.

   ```
   <xsl:template match="import:file">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
       <xsl:for-each-group select=".//import:reference" group-by="import:table">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:copy-of select="import:table" />
           <import:link>
             <source><xsl:value-of select="../import:target" /></source>
             <target><xsl:value-of select="import:field" /></target>
           </import:link>
         </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   ```

Putting it together:

```
<xsl:transform
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:import="http://schemas.company.com/wsdl/domain/v2/import"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="import:file">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      <xsl:for-each-group select=".//import:reference" group-by="import:table">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="import:table" />
          <import:link>
            <source><xsl:value-of select="../import:target" /></source>
            <target><xsl:value-of select="import:field" /></target>
          </import:link>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="import:reference" />
</xsl:transform>
```

Produces pretty much exactly your desired result:

```
<import:configuration xmlns:import="http://schemas.company.com/wsdl/domain/v2/import">
   <import:input>
      <import:file headers="1" group="MAPPING">
         <import:name>file001.txt</import:name>
         <import:separator>;</import:separator>
         <import:table>TAB00008_TECSPEC</import:table>
         <import:field primary="true">
            <import:name>VEMAR</import:name>
            <import:target>VEMAR</import:target>
            <import:type dbs="oracle" type="text">VARCHAR(3)</import:type>
            <import:description/>
         </import:field>
         <import:field primary="true">
            <import:name>VENR</import:name>
            <import:target>VENR</import:target>
            <import:type dbs="oracle" type="numeric">NUMBER(7)</import:type>
            <import:description/>
         </import:field>
         <import:field primary="true">
            <import:name>KNR</import:name>
            <import:target>KNR</import:target>
            <import:type dbs="oracle" type="numeric">NUMBER(9)</import:type>
            <import:description/>
         </import:field>
         <import:field>
            <import:name>DATNEU</import:name>
            <import:target>DATNEU</import:target>
            <import:type dbs="oracle" type="date" format="YYYY.MM.DD">DATE</import:type>
            <import:description/>
         </import:field>
         <import:field>
            <import:name>VTYPE</import:name>
            <import:target>VTYPE</import:target>
            <import:type dbs="oracle" type="numeric">NUMBER(1)</import:type>
            <import:description/>
         </import:field>
         <import:description/>
         <import:reference>
            <import:table>TAB00006_TECSPEC</import:table>
            <import:link>
               <source>VEMAR</source>
               <target>VEMAR</target>
            </import:link>
         </import:reference>
         <import:reference>
            <import:table>TAB00003_TECSPEC</import:table>
            <import:link>
               <source>KNR</source>
               <target>KNR</target>
            </import:link>
         </import:reference>
      </import:file>
   </import:input>
</import:configuration>
```

This does not include the `xmlns:xsi` attribute in the output (wasn't part of the original question). You can add that in the same fashion, by writing a template that modifies `import:configuration`:

```
<xsl:template match="import:configuration">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">http://schemas.company.com/wsdl/domain/v2/import C:/Users/Ruben/Downloads/tmp/new/xsd/import_config.xsd</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You could move the `xsi` namespace prefix declaration to the root level in the XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

This worked (it brings my near to my desired target):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.company.com/wsdl/domain/v2/import" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="ns0 xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <configuration xmlns="http://schemas.company.com/wsdl/domain/v2/import">
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" select="'http://schemas.company.com/wsdl/domain/v2/import C:/Users/Ruben/Downloads/tmp/new/xsd/import_config.xsd'"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:configuration">
                <input>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:input/ns0:file">
                        <xsl:variable name="var1_group" as="node()?" select="@group"/>
                        <file>
                            <xsl:attribute name="headers" namespace="" select="xs:string(xs:integer(fn:string(@headers)))"/>
                            <xsl:if test="fn:exists($var1_group)">
                                <xsl:attribute name="group" namespace="" select="fn:string($var1_group)"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <name>
                                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ns0:name)"/>
                            </name>
                            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:directory">
                                <directory>
                                    <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                </directory>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <separator>
                                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ns0:separator)"/>
                            </separator>
                            <table>
                                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ns0:table)"/>
                            </table>
                            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:field">
                                <xsl:variable name="var2_primary" as="node()?" select="@primary"/>
                                <field>
                                    <xsl:if test="fn:exists($var2_primary)">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="primary" namespace="" select="xs:string(xs:boolean(fn:string($var2_primary)))"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <name>
                                        <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ns0:name)"/>
                                    </name>
                                    <target>
                                        <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ns0:target)"/>
                                    </target>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:type">
                                        <type>
                                            <xsl:sequence select="(./@node(), ./node())"/>
                                        </type>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <description>
                                        <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ns0:description)"/>
                                    </description>
                                </field>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:field">
                                <xsl:variable name="var3_current" as="node()" select="."/>
                                <xsl:for-each select="ns0:reference">
                                    <reference>
                                        <table>
                                            <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ns0:table)"/>
                                        </table>
                                        <link>
                                            <source>
                                                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string($var3_current/ns0:target)"/>
                                            </source>
                                            <target>
                                                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ns0:field)"/>
                                            </target>
                                        </link>
                                    </reference>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <description>
                                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ns0:description)"/>
                            </description>
                        </file>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </input>
                <description>
                    <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ns0:description)"/>
                </description>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </configuration>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That does not produce the result you said you wanted in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I know that, it is work in progress and I'm getting closer to my result. As I already told, I'm new and I'm just trying. Bye